# no such table : main.core_answer__old

Tags: python, django, database, sqlite

I tried to create a new Comment based on these models :

```
class Answer(models.Model):
answer = models.TextField()
author = models.ForeignKey(CustomUser, on_delete = models.CASCADE,
                           related_name="written_answers")
question = models.ForeignKey(Question, on_delete = models.CASCADE, related_name="answers")
upvoters = models.ManyToManyField(CustomUser, related_name="upvoted_answers")
created_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add = True, blank = True)
updated_at = models.DateTimeField(blank = True, null=True)

def __str__(self):
    return str(self.id)
```

```
class Comment(models.Model):
    comment = models.CharField(max_length = 200)
    author = models.ForeignKey(CustomUser, on_delete = models.CASCADE,
                               related_name = "written_comments")
    answer = models.ForeignKey(Answer, on_delete = models.CASCADE, related_name="comments")
    upvoters = models.ManyToManyField(CustomUser, related_name="upvoted_comments")
    parent_comment = models.ForeignKey("self", on_delete = models.CASCADE,
                                          related_name="next_in_thread", null=True, blank=False)
    created_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add = True, blank = True)
    updated_at = models.DateTimeField(null=True, blank = True)

    class Meta:
        ordering = ('created_at', )
```

But I get the following error : no such table : main.core_answer__old
What did I do wrong? I tried to delete the SQLite table and the migrations and start over, but this error still persists. Please help.

Edit : 
I'm using a populating script after migrating, which creates Questions and Answers, if that makes a difference.

core/models.py

```
from django.db import models
from users.models import CustomUser

class Genre(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=84)
    subscribers = models.ManyToManyField(CustomUser, related_name="subscribed_genres")

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name

class Topic(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=84)
    followers = models.ManyToManyField(CustomUser, related_name="followed_topics")

    def __str__(self):
        return "#" + self.name

class Question(models.Model):
    question = models.CharField(max_length = 128, blank = False)
    asker = models.ForeignKey(CustomUser, on_delete = models.CASCADE, 
                              related_name="asked_questions")
    requested = models.ManyToManyField(CustomUser, related_name="answer_requests")
    genres = models.ManyToManyField(Genre, related_name = "questions")
    followers = models.ManyToManyField(CustomUser, related_name="followed_questions")
    topics = models.ManyToManyField(Topic, related_name="questions")
    url = models.CharField(max_length = 150, unique=True)
    created_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add = True, blank = True)
    updated_at = models.DateTimeField(null=True, blank = True)

    class Meta:
        ordering = ('-created_at', )

    def __str__(self):
        return self.question

class Answer(models.Model):
    answer = models.TextField()
    author = models.ForeignKey(CustomUser, on_delete = models.CASCADE,
                               related_name="written_answers")
    question = models.ForeignKey(Question, on_delete = models.CASCADE, related_name="answers")
    upvoters = models.ManyToManyField(CustomUser, related_name="upvoted_answers")
    created_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add = True, blank = True)
    updated_at = models.DateTimeField(blank = True, null=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return str(self.id)

class Comment(models.Model):
    comment = models.CharField(max_length = 200)
    author = models.ForeignKey(CustomUser, on_delete = models.CASCADE,
                               related_name = "written_comments")
    answer = models.ForeignKey(Answer, on_delete = models.CASCADE, related_name="replied_comments")
    upvoters = models.ManyToManyField(CustomUser, related_name="upvoted_comments")
    parent_comment = models.ForeignKey("self", on_delete = models.CASCADE,
                                          related_name="next_in_thread", null=True, blank=False)
    created_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add = True, blank = True)
    updated_at = models.DateTimeField(null=True, blank = True)

    class Meta:
        ordering = ('created_at', )
```

**[RESOLVED] : Upgraded from Django==2.1 to Django==2.2**

Comment: show your installed apps in settings.

Comment: ```
INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    'core',
    'rest_framework',
    'rest_framework.authtoken',
    'corsheaders',
    'users',
]
```

Comment: So you have an `Core` app and error saying that it couldn't find a table for that app. Is there a model for it?

Comment: Adding core/models.py to the question, please check that.

Comment: Hm, it feels like there was an previous version (old) for the Core model and somewhere in the code you still having the referrence to that table (or rather one of the fields). Can you search in the code base for `Core` occurrences to check if something still pointing to not existing fields?

Comment: I'm deleting the database, creating new migrations, then simply using Comment.objects.create() from shell. Not referring to any old core models here far as I know..

Comment: I upgraded to Django==2.2 from 2.1 and now this error is gone !